# dotnet publish -o published is created nested directories with each publish

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-publish

I have an ASP Core project named `MyProject` that I'm trying to publish to the directory `MyProject\published`.  I run `dotnet publish -o published`.  This works correctly the first time.  However, the second time that I run this, the files get published to `MyProject\published\published`.  The third time it gets published to `MyProject\published\published\published`, and so on.  Why does each subsequent publish create one more nested directory, rather than just overwriting `MyProject\published`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems is a known issue about dotnet sdk :

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/377

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2855

The current alternatives appear to be manually deleting stale files or adding custom tasks for cleanups.

Answer (score 1):

This is now mentioned officially in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

First, delete your current bin/release-folder (otherwise it won't work!).
Then you can add

```
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);publish**</DefaultItemExcludes>
```

to a PropertyGroup element in the .csproj file.
The above example assumes, the publish-folder is named *publish* (please change it if necessary)